# Final r on Request File name issue rewrite apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a really, really strange problem.
I use this Rewrite Rule on my website

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to tranform url like this:
 
`www.mywebsite.com/page`
Into this:
`www.mywebsite.com/page/`

The Rule work but not for only one page:

```
mywebsite.com/register
```

For this page the result is:

```
www.mywebsite.com/registe/
```

It cut the final r and i don't know why. For all page (login, home, confirm etc..) work but not for this.
Thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use this rule for adding trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

And remember to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.